# Recognize byte strings

Tags: python, arrays, unicode, ascii

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to recognize different strings in my byte array. Let me elaborate, for example:

```
b'libgcj-13.dll\x00_Jv_RegisterClasses\x00\x00\x00unhandled vlc exception\n\x00\x00w\x00,\x00 \x00c\x00c\x00s\x00=\x00U\x00T\x00F\x00-\x008\x00\x00\x00\nerror while opening file\x00\x00\x00[\x00v\x00e\x00r\x00s\x00i\x00o\x00n\x00]\x00\n\x00O\x00S\x00=\x00%\x00d\x00.\x00%\x00'
```

This is only a small part but for obvious reasons i'll only post a small part. What I except from the byte array are strings formatted in either 'ascii' or 'unicode'. With the eye is pretty easy to recognize different strings in the array.

```
libgcj-13.dll followed by a Null terminator - Ascii
_Jv_registerclasses followed by a Null terminator - Ascii
unhandled vlc exception followed by a Null terminator -Ascii
w, css=UTF-8 followed by a Null terminator - Unicode
```

Now the problem starts when I read the byte array per byte. The first 3 strings will not produce any problems until I reach the first Unicode string. When I read per byte I receive "\x00w" as "\x00" and "w" separated. The "\x00" isn't a null terminator but part of "\x00w". The following list make it somewhat clear:

```
b'\x00', b'\x00', b'w', b'\x00', b',', b'\x00', b' ', b'\x00', b'c', b'\x00', b'c', b'\x00', b's', b'\x00', b'=', b'\x00', b'U', b'\x00', b'T', b'\x00', b'F', b'\x00', b'-', b'\x00', b'8', b'\x00'
```

From the point I am receiving Unicode characters I should read per 2 bytes instead of 1 so I don't read them as Null terminator but as Unicode characters instead. Now my question is there a way to detect this? or solve this problem otherwise?

Hopefully I explained it well enough, 
with Kinds regards

Comment: Note: UTF-8 is a superset of ASCII. All your ASCII data could equally be classified as UTF-8.

Comment: It looks like you have data that has been encoded with some kind of record scheme; strings being null-terminated and perhaps padded to a minimal length. Figure out the encoding scheme and you'll have a much easier time to decode it.

Comment: You do also appear to have UTF-16 data (2 bytes per character, characters in the ASCII and Latin-1 ranges are then using just one of the two bytes with the other byte being a null).

Comment: I see `ccs=UTF-8`, `\nerror while opening file`, `[version]` and `OS=%d.%` in there, for example, but without the specific scheme this is not automatible.

Comment: Maybe for some extra information, the byte string is from the PE file .rdata section. The only information i'm able to retrieve are the alignment values. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680341(v=vs.85).aspx